# Seg faults when writing my own find program

Tags: c, linux, unix

So just to clarify. This is for a school assignment. We are writing a simplified find program (sfind), and I am running into an issue.

Basically, the -print flag works perfectly in any situation where there isn't a huge amount to look at. However, when I try to run it from my base directory, (which has a large amount of files) I eventually run into seg faults. I feel this could be for any number of reasons.

1. My user process limit is too low
2. My max file size is too low
3. I am getting stack overflow for too deep of recursion
4. Some other thing I am overlooking

I am running this on ubuntu, and it will eventaully be turned in on a Unix server.

Here is my current recursion code.

```
int printHelper(struct dirent *entry, DIR *dir, char* path){
    struct stat fileStat;
    DIR *tempDir;
    char tempPath[1000];
    char const* name = entry->d_name;
    strcpy(tempPath, path);
    strcat(tempPath, name);
    lstat(tempPath, &fileStat);
    if(strcmp(name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(name, "..") != 0){
        printf("%s%s\n", path, name);
    }
    if((S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) && (strcmp(name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(name, "..") != 0)){
        struct dirent *tempEntr;
        char newTempPath[1000];
        char newPathName[1000];
        strcpy(newPathName, name);
        strcpy(newTempPath, path);
        strcat(newTempPath, newPathName);
        strcat(newTempPath, slashPath);
        tempDir = opendir(newTempPath);
        tempEntr = readdir(tempDir);
        printHelper(tempEntr, tempDir, newTempPath);
        closedir(tempDir);
    }
    if(!(entry = readdir(dir))){
            return 0;
    }
    printHelper(entry, dir, path);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the beginning of the file

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myPrint.h"

char slashPath[3] = "/\0";

int myPrint(char const* myFile){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    int isDir;
    isDir = 1;

    if (!(dir = opendir(myFile))){
        isDir = 0;
    }
    else if (!(entry = readdir(dir))){
        return -1;
    }
    if(isDir == 0){
        dir = opendir(".");
        while((entry = readdir(dir))){
            if(strcmp(myFile, entry->d_name) == 0){
                printf("%s\n", myFile);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        printf("find: ‘%s’: No such file or directory\n", myFile);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        char path[2000];
        strcpy(path, myFile);
        strcat(path, slashPath);
        printf("%s\n", myFile);
        printHelper(entry, dir, path);
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because you have no base case

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Because there is more to the code. I'll edit it in

Comment: Time to use the debugger.

Comment: very bad coding ! use strncpy and strncat ! Use a size value for all pointer to a string please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a recursive call for every **file** that you're processing.  The call stack will get deep fast and you'll overflow the stack.

Change the code to recurse on each directory instead of each file.  Have the function accept just a directory path.  Then open the directory and use a `while` loop to go through each entry.  If the entry is a directory, *then* make a recursive call with the name of the subdirectory.

Comment: Ah, so you mean, at the end when I call print helper on itself with all the same stuff it was originally called with, instead make that a while loop? I think that makes sense

Comment: @Joe Not just the end.  Start the function by calling `opendir`, then use `while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)` the read the entries, then `closedir` at the end.

Comment: Yeah I've got that in now. Thanks so much. I was seriously stumped.